# jQuery Plugin Function return

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins

I have a jQuery plugin which will return a function to call it later.
This is necessary because the plugin needs to be refreshed if the elements change. So for example you can call:

```
$('.test').test()
```

and if you did a change of all .test-elements, than you can refresh the jQuery plugin with

```
$('.test').test().init()
```

But everytime I call `$('.test').test().init()` the function will be executed two times. Can you tell me why?

http://jsfiddle.net/WBE8Q/

Comment: Because `test()` calls `init()`.  And then you call `init()`.

Comment: Probably because just calling test() also calls init(), so calling init() again makes it two times,

Comment: Thanks, but what would be a solution? I only want to call the function init() inside test() if the elements changed, but not the whole plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling init() within test(), so the line

```
$('.test').test().init();
```

means that init() will be called twice.  [In addition to the single time it's called when first call test()].  You're returning the function pointer, but not ever calling it.  What if you did this instead within your ready() function?

```
var func = $('.test').test(); 
setTimeout(function(){
    func.init();
},1000);
```